# How to load assemblies from file in dotnet core 1.1

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, .net-core-1.1

My project was on `dotnet core 1.0` and I used the below line to load assemblies from files, and it was working fine.

```
assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(file.FullName);
```

Now I update my project to `dotnet core 1.1`,and I get below exception

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'PartyManagement, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>      at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromPath(IntPtr ptrNativeAssemblyLoadContext, String ilPath, String niPath, ObjectHandleOnStack retAssembly)
>      at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath(String assemblyPath)
>      at Tuba.Framework.Builder.MetaDataDirector.Build() in C:\projects\Tuba\Tuba\src\Framework\Tuba.Framework\Builder\MetaDataDirector.cs:line 36